# Certificate Pinning in OKHttp with Certificate file

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, okhttp, certificate-pinning

The Android `network-security-config` and OKHttp Client is support **Public Key Pinning** like.

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">my_domain.com</domain>
        <pin-set expiration="2018-01-01">
            <pin digest="SHA-256">7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

```
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add("my_domain", "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")
    .build();
```

However, in my case, I will need to pin the **Certificate** file (even it can expired), instead of **Public Key**. Because Certificate file is more secure and iOS is pinning Certificate file with `ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(...)`.

I haven't found any built-in methods to support Certificate file pin that can check the expiration. What I tried is

1. Use `trust-anchors` with my domain certificate

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">my_domain.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/myDomainCA"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

This way work but I can not have any fallback for the expiration

2. Use `HandshakeCertificates`

```
val certificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
    .addTrustedCertificate(myDomainCA)
    .build()

val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(certificates.sslSocketFactory(), certificates.trustManager)
    .build()
```

With this way, I can handle my domain's certificate expiration, but I can't connect to other servers. I want to pin certificate only for my domain, without adding certificates for all the other servers I use. Moreover, if I add `addPlatformTrustedCertificates()`, then the certificate pinning for my domain does not work.

Is there any other approach to pin certificate file in Android?